# ReactiveUI.Validation: this.IsValid() updated after ReactiveCommand is invoked

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm starting out in using ReactiveUI.Validation. When using this.IsValid() as the parameter for CanExecute in a ReactiveCommand.Create(), the IsValid is one user input "late".

This is a ViewModel.cs to reproduce the problem, for testing I bind it to a WPF TextBox:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject<ViewModel>
{
    private readonly ReactiveCommand<string, Unit> Command;

    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => _myProperty;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _myProperty, value);
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Command = ReactiveCommand.Create<string>(x => SetMyProperty(x), this.IsValid());

        this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyProperty)
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Property value = " + x))
            .InvokeCommand(Command);

        this.ValidationRule(
            viewModel => viewModel.MyProperty,
            x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Length > 3,
            "Enter a value");

        this.IsValid()
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("IsValid = " + x));
    }

    private Unit SetMyProperty(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered method");
        return Unit.Default;
    }
}
```

This is the Console output I get (notice when the command is executed):

```
Property value = 1  
Property value = 12  
Property value = 123  
Property value = 1234  
IsValid = True  
Property value = 12345  
Entered method  
Property value = 1234  
Entered method  
Property value = 123  
Entered method  
IsValid = False  
Property value = 12  
Property value = 1
```

This is the console output I would expect:

```
Property value = 1  
Property value = 12  
Property value = 123  
Property value = 1234  
IsValid = True  
Entered method  
Property value = 12345  
Entered method  
Property value = 1234  
Entered method  
Property value = 123  
IsValid = False  
Property value = 12  
Property value = 1
```

Am I using it correctly? Is there a way to force the validation before the InvokeCommand?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This issue looks like an issue where the user keeps modifying the property and the validation rule event ends up falling behind.  You can probably resolve the issue by using Throttle() on your property observable (The one that calls InvokeCommand())

Comment: E.g. `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyProperty)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Property value = " + x))
            .InvokeCommand(Command);`

Comment: `Throttle()` does work. Is that a robust solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the good folks at GitHub: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/issues/92

Copy of the post on GitHub:

> If you place a call to this.WhenAnyValue below a call to this.ValidationRule, you'll get the following behavior:
>
> IsValid = False
> Property value = 1
> Property value = 12
> Property value = 123
> IsValid = True
> Property value = 1234
> Entered method
> Property value = 12345
> Entered method
> Property value = 1234
> Entered method
> IsValid = False
> Property value = 123
> Property value = 12
> Property value = 1
>
> The modified code looks as such:

```
    public class ViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject<ViewModel>
    {
        private readonly ReactiveCommand<string, Unit> Command;
    
        private string _myProperty;
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get => _myProperty;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _myProperty, value);
        }
    
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Command = ReactiveCommand.Create<string>(x => SetMyProperty(x), this.IsValid());
    
            this.ValidationRule(
                viewModel => viewModel.MyProperty,
                x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Length > 3,
                "Enter a value");
            
            // The call to WhenAny is now placed below a call to ValidationRule.
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyProperty)
                .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Property value = " + x))
                .InvokeCommand(Command);
    
            this.IsValid()
                .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("IsValid = " + x));
        }
    
        private Unit SetMyProperty(string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entered method");
            return Unit.Default;
        }
    }
```

> Both WhenAny and ValidationRule are using CurrentThreadScheduler since #97, so the call order matters now. Hopefully we will deploy the new version of the package to NuGet soon.

It works with the new version 1.6.4 of ReactiveUI.Validation

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to get out of that situation:

### Solution 1: Don't use `InvokeCommand`

The obvious one is not to use `InvokeCommand` if you want to bypass the validation under any circumstances. Check the [documentation of `InvokeCommand()`](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/#invoking-commands-in-an-observable-pipeline):

> **Hint** `InvokeCommand` respects the command's executability. That is, if the command's `CanExecute` method returns `false`, `InvokeCommand` will not execute the command when the source observable ticks.

So you might want to call the `SetMyProperty()` method directly instead via the command.

### Solution 2: Delay the subscription on `MyProperty`

You can use the [`Observable.Delay()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211968(v=vs.103)) extension to wait for a small amount of time before reacting for the property change. That way you can "give enough time" for the `IsValid()` check to switch before doing your `InvokeCommand` call. The code might look like this:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyProperty)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Property value = " + x))
    .InvokeCommand(Command);
```

Comment: **Solution 1:** I want some kind of validation to prevent entering invalid values to my model. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. **Solution 2:** It works with 100ms, 10ms but not 1ms. It also works with Throttle. Is that a robust solution? I always thought that a delay to allow tasks to synchronize was a bad idea. Thanks for the feed back!

Comment: @AntoineL Yes, using delay/throttle to sync threads isn't the right way to sync threads, it's a lazy fix. I just haven't found a different way to solve it, but I'm sure there is one. For the solution 1 part: you can use the `ValidationContext.IsValid` property in the `SetMyProperty` method to check if the method was called when the validation context was valid (and throw an exception when it is not).

Comment: When I access `ValidationContext.IsValid` it's also not representing the refreshed validated state of my property (just like `this.IsValid()`). So it doesn't work. I'm trying to find a method in the GitHub of `ReactiveUI.Validation` that will force the execution of the validation before the `InvokeCommand`, but no luck yet.

Comment: @AntoineL The extension method `IsValid()` is defined as `IObservable<bool>` so you get informed when the valid flag is changed. I tried to use it with `CombineLatest()` on the property change to react only when it is `true`, but it didn't quite worked for me. Maybe you can check if you can use the observable returned by `IsValid()`.

Comment: I scanned through most of the Rx operators and I cant find what could do the trick. I'll keep the question unanswered for now to see if more ideas come in.

Comment: You should probably use Throttle() in place of Delay(), since Throttle will ignore all but the last change in a series of changes.  So if the user types 12345 quickly in sequence, Throttle will cause the observable to only fire once on 12345, rather than 1, then 12, then 123, then 1234, then 12345.  This should allow your IsValid and InvokeCommand calls to be fairly synchronized.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug in ReactiveUI.Validation, so ideally we should somehow debug this and fix on ReactiveUI.Validation side https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui.validation

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/issues/92